# Registering db context provider with provided config options

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to add DB context as a service, and immediately provide connection string.

`appsettings.json`:

```
"DatabaseSettings": {
    "ConnectionString": "User Id=system;Password=system;Data Source=localhost:1521/XEPDB1",
    "Schema": "HOME",
    "MigrationTableName": "__EFMigrationsHistory"
}
```

`Program.cs`:

```
builder.Configuration
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

builder.Services.Configure<DatabaseSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(DatabaseSettings)));
```

Then I try to register my db context:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>((p, m) =>
        {
             // var databaseSettings = ???
            
             m.UseOracle(databaseSettings.ConnectionString, ob =>
                 ob.MigrationsHistoryTable(databaseSettings.MigrationTableName, 
             databaseSettings.Schema));
        });
```

How do I resolve specific options type (`DatabaseSettings`) in that scenario? I can only do `GetSection` which just returns an unmapped `IConfigurationSection`. Can I somehow map it directly to a `DatabaseSettings` object?

Answer (score 0):

Works with [`ConfigurationBinder.Get<T>()` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.get?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#microsoft-extensions-configuration-configurationbinder-get-1(microsoft-extensions-configuration-iconfiguration)).

```cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>((p, m) =>
{
    var databaseSettings = builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(DatabaseSettings))
        .Get<DatabaseSettings>();
            
    m.UseOracle(databaseSettings.ConnectionString, ob =>
        ob.MigrationsHistoryTable(databaseSettings.MigrationTableName, 
    databaseSettings.Schema));
});
```

Reference: 
[Bind hierarchical configuration data using the options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#bind-hierarchical-configuration-data-using-the-options-pattern)